# InnoSetup ExtractTemporaryFile causes heavy delay?

Tags: inno-setup, bass.dll

So I have an InnoSetup script that extracts an audio file to be played. 
Works great for smallish setups around 60MB

However for larger setups, say 200+MB the extraction takes ages and the wizard doesnt show up but hangs invisible.

Playing with Bass Audio Lib with procedure InitializeWizard; or function InitializeSetup()

Any idea ?

Comment: Files you want to `ExtractTemporary` should be added as the `First Positions` in `[Files]` section. It is also good to use `Flags: nocompression`. Also use `SolidCompression=False` in `[Setup]` section. But still extracting multiple files or large files may take some time.

Comment: Change the compression algorithm to zip. LZ is super slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files you want to `ExtractTemporary` should be added as the `First Positions` in `[Files`] section.

It is also good to use `Flags: nocompression` (for large files) 
and **NOT** to use `SolidCompression=True` (False is the Default) in `[Setup]` section.

But still extracting multiple files or large files may take some time.